# Equivalence of dual spaces of Sobolev Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, sobolev-spaces

I have a quick question: Is the following equivalence true for Sobolev Spaces $(W^{1,p}(\Omega))^{*} = W^{-1,p}(\Omega) = (W^{1,p}_{0}(\Omega))^{*}$ where $W^{1,p}_{0}(\Omega)$ is the closure of $C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$. Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true.

You only have 
$$(W^{1,p}_0(\Omega))^*=W^{-1,p}(\Omega)  $$
However, the dual space of $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is not identified, although it is smaller then $W^{-1,p}(\Omega)$.

For more information, please read 10.4 in [Leoni](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821847686)'s book, it has a complete treatment of dual of Sobolev space.

Comment: Does $W^{-1,p}(\Omega)$ not denote the dual of $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$? What notation is used to denote the dual space of $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$?

Comment: Please be careful. The notation $W^{-1,p}(\Omega)$ only denote the dual of $W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$. There is no special symbol for the dual of $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ other then $(W^{1,p}(\Omega))^*$. I also update my answer, please have a look.